# Centralizando logo dentro de uma lista (ul)

Tags: html, css

Há alguma maneira de centralizar o logo desse [exemplo](http://demo.andthemes.com/dine-and-drink-3)
sem usar duas listas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No site do exemplo, ele usa duas listas para poder manter o logo no centro, como posso colocar o logo dentro de uma "li" sem afetar a estrutura do menu?

Comment: Como assim duas listas? queres ter o logo no meio das `<li>` de um menu? Podes descrever melhor o que devemos procurar no outro site?

Comment: observe que no outro site há duas <ul> para um único menu, o que não é eficiente. <ul> logo <ul>. Eu estou querendo uma maneira melhor para fazer a mesma coisa, sem usar duas <ul> e colocar o logo dentro de uma <li>. A melhor maneira que encontrei até agora foi essa http://stanhub.com/how-to-center-a-logo-in-unordered-list-navigation-using-css3-nth-child-selector/

Comment: Não percebo bem o problema. Parece simples. Podes explicar a partir deste exemplo? -> http://jsfiddle.net/y9jLte8s/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9jLte8s/1/
quando tento colocar o logo, ele desalinha a estrutura, como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Não sei se percebi bem o que queres... queres chegar a imagem mais para baixo? assim -> http://jsfiddle.net/y9jLte8s/2/ ?

Comment: isso mesmo!! Agora como removo o espaço que sobrou em cima?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9jLte8s/4/ <-

Comment: @Sergio excelente, cria uma resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes inserir a imagem dentro de um dos `<li>` e depois usar `position` e `top` para ajustar a posição desse elemento.

Como tu próprio sugeriste ter uma classe especifica nesse elemento é util.
Assim o HTML seria:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="logo"><a href=""><img src="/favicon.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

e o CSS importante:

```
.nav ul li{
    float: left;
}
.logo {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9jLte8s/4/

Answer (score 1):

Montei um exemplo no CodePen http://codepen.io/guidiego/pen/ZGxZbj usando Bootstrap e SCSS, porem deixo alguns alertas:

Eu usaria o nav-pills para poder espaçar o ultimo li da primeira parte (:nth-child(2)) e deixaria o logo fora da LI, o unico motivo é a responsividade, fica dificil tratar o menu quando tem um elemento que não pertence a ele!

A forma abordada tambem não é das melhores, eu particularmente só uso position:absolute em questões extremas!

De qualquer forma fica a o codigo e a dica :)

Abraços